# Adjoint of $2\times2$ Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to do Adjoint of $3\times3$ matrix but how do I do it for just $2\times2$?

Say the matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & i \\ 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{matrix} cof(a_{11}) = -1 & cof(a_{12})= 1\\cof(a_{21}) = i & cof(a_{22}) = 1\end{matrix}$$

Now take

$$Adj A = \frac{1}{\det A}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1\\i&1\end{pmatrix}^{T}$$